# Может ли SQLite делать бэкап на сервер SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

Вопрос, пожалуй, нубский однако ответа на просторах интернета я к сожалению не нашел.
Я разрабатываю десктопное приложение на C#, которое автоматизирует заполнение медкарт, ведение графика приёма и прочей медицинской бумажной работы. Пришёл к выводу что данные лучше хранить с помощью SQLite, так как при установке приложения база будет доступна без отправки запросов на локальный сервер. Однако в функциях программы я собираюсь делать периодический бэкап на удаленный SQL Server. Есть ли в SQLite подобная возможность? Если есть, я бы был благодарен за пример реализации таковой.

Comment: насколько мне известно, такой возможности нет

Comment: То что вы хотите сделать называется “bulk upsert SQL Server”. Попробуйте погуглить с этой строкой поиска...

Comment: Просто поднимаете два соединения, читаете из локальной бд и пишете в удалённую.

Comment: В каком виде вы хотите хранить бэкап? Можно же просто файл БД sqlite целиком сохранить в виде блоба в SqlServer.

Comment: А при ресторе с сервера она какой будет возвращаться? Как файл базы данных и заменять существующую?